# Continuous Maximum Flow Problem

Tags: continuity, network-flow

[Maximum Flow Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem), but continuous.

Suppose there are two points on a plane, the $source$ and the $sink$. There's also $capacity$ of each point on the plane: the maximum amount that can flow through this point in a unit of time. Capacity is a continuous function $\left( \Bbb R , \Bbb R \right) \to \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$.

A $flow$ is a series of $streams$. A stream is a pair: $rate \ of \ flow$ ($\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$), the amount that actually flows in a unit of time, plus the $path of flow$, the points that the flow goes through, also continuous: $$\left[ 0, 1 \right] \to \left( \Bbb R , \Bbb R \right), 0 \to source, 1 \to sink$$

A flow is $invalid$ if there's a point such that the sum of all rates of flow through it is higher than it's capacity.

Is it possible to calculate the maximum valid flow and construct an example of such a flow?

Bonus: prove an equivalent of the [Max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) and construct an example of a cut!

Comment: The "collection of paths" is cumbersome to define in such a way that the problem is well posed, since the space of paths from source to sink is very large and difficult to work with. A much more straightforward method would be to use a velocity vector field (as in fluid mechanics): the flow rate through a surface is simply the flux.

Also, using all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (rather than e.g. a closed subset) presents the problem of flows escaping to infinity.

The end result will probably look something like the [Eikonal Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation).

Comment: See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02592050) for a (somewhat technical) treatment of the continuous max-flow/min-cut duality.

Comment: I thought about using a vector field, but I don't know how to specify that the total influx and outflux of a point should be equal. Is there a good definition, and does it follow from the vector field being continuous?

Comment: Also please post the paper as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02592050) gives a treatment of the general treatment of the continuous min-flow/max-cut duality. I won't go into the details of the proof of duality, but the general setup of the problem is as follows:

In place of a network, let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, bounded subset whose boundary $\Gamma$ is a smooth surface with unit normal $n$. A flow field $\sigma:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth vector field. The sources and sinks can be distributed over the interior and boundary by two functions $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ which determine the relative strength of sources, which impose the folowing constraints, where $\lambda$ allows al in/outflows to be scaled together.:
$$
\text{div}\ \sigma=\lambda F,\ \ \ n\cdot\text{div}\ \sigma=\lambda f
$$
Additionally, there is a maximum flow rate at each point, given by a smooth function $c:\Omega\to R$, which imposes the constraint $\|\sigma\|\le c$. The overall problem can be stated as
$$
\text{maximize}_{\sigma,\lambda}\ \ \ \lambda \\
\text{subject to}\ \ \ \text{div}\ \sigma=\lambda F,\ \ \ n\cdot\text{div}\ \sigma=\lambda f,\ \ \ \|\sigma\|\le c
$$
Your description of the problem uses two points, a source and sink, which I'll call $p$ and $q$ respectively. We can fit this into the above language by allowing $\sigma$ to be undefined at $p$ and $q$ and letting $F(x)=\delta(x-p)-\delta(x-q)$ and $f(x)=0$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

If you want to use all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a problem of sources and sinks "at infinity". These can be eliminated by requiring $\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{S(r)}c=0$, where $S(r)$ is a sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin. The arguments in the paper may require additional care to verify that integrals converge, but the same duality should apply.

Comment: Thanks for the summary!

Maybe a better way to apply the "exactly one source and exactly one sink" simplification to the continuous case is to place the source and the sink outside the Ω. Instead of a single maximum flow rate, there'd be three: lateral flow rate, inflow and outflow.